# How to answer the incoming call from the customized on screen popup

Tags: lync, ucma, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

I'm developing a sample Lync Wpf application. In which we have customized our own popup with accept and ignore buttons like below, whenever we got a call popup will be called. Here we need to handle the call when we click on accept button need to answer the call or ignore button is clicked end the call. Can anyone suggest me with any sample code in answering or accepting calls?

[image]

Thanks,
D Haraveer